# -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution doesn't print size per age

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I wrote simple program which infinitely addes objects into collection and I wanted to see standard output for PrintTenuringDistribution option:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        persons.add(new Person("jorik", "kornev"));
    }
}
```

As a program output I'm getting:

```
Desired survivor size 5242880 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 15)

Desired survivor size 5242880 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 15)

Desired survivor size 5242880 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 15)
```

Actually I suggested that I would get something like this:

```
Desired survivor size 75497472 bytes, new threshold 15 (max 15)
- age   1:   19321624 bytes,   19321624 total
- age   2:      79376 bytes,   19401000 total
- age   3:    2904256 bytes,   22305256 total
```

I'm using JDK 1.7.0_79 with VM options:

```
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

So, could you please advice what I'm doing wrong and how I can get desired output.

Thanks, Evgeniy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/throughput_collector_and_printtenuringdistribution_option) it's working as intended.

> Well, this is the expected behavior and is not a bug. Throughput
>   collector does not use the age table like the other collectors do. And
>   due to that reason, the age histogram information is not printed with
>   the throughput collector. With the throughput collector, we can only
>   see the desired survivor size, threshold age, and the maximum
>   threshold age with PrintTenuringDistribution option.